# How to set Array String through JS Post Back to Web Method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, string, methods

How to send array strings with JS post back to Web Method in ASP.NET, code sample is below:

```
function service() {
            var items = $('#jqxTree').jqxTree('getCheckedItems');
            //  var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: items });
            myData = {};
            for (index in items) {
                myData[index] = items[index].label;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ServiceConfiguration.aspx/ProcessIndexes",
                data: "{'jsonValue': " + JSON.stringify(myData) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {

                }
            });
            //alert(items);
        }
```

now i am trying with following:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static void ProcessIndexes(List<string> jsonValue)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();


        }
```

Comment: You need to show some code

Comment: You have single quotes around `jsonValue`... JSON requires double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile since I've been in .NET land, but something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SomeForm.aspx/SomeWebMethod",
    data: JSON.stringify({ someValues: ["foo", "bar"] }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp) {
        // handle success here
    },
    error: function() {
        // handle error here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @jmar777, let me check with this and if it works i'll get back to you with lots of appreciations :-) because my head banged with this :(

Comment: I also just noticed that your WebMethod is expecting a `List<string>`, whereas my example is posting an entire JSON object (with the array nested inside it).  This is getting outside the realm of what I remember, but I think that'll need to be addressed.  Perhaps just accept a `String jsonValue` and then deserialize it with your `JavaScriptSerializer`...